# Regex no Python para encontrar varias possibilidades de nomes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Preciso encontrar o nome do juiz num arquivo de processo trabalhista, mas antes preciso saber se ele é Juiz(a), Relator(a), Juiz(a) Relator(a) ou Desembargador(a).

Estou usando o seguinte Regex:

```
f_regex = re.compile(r'ju(iz|íza) relato(r|a) | ju(iz|íza) | relato(r|a) | desembargado(r|ra)')
```

Mas não está funcionando.

**EDIT:**

**Problema resolvido.**
O problema nao era no regex e sim dentro de uma funçao minha. Desculpem pelo incoveniente, tambem nao sabia o que estava acontecendo. Gratidao a todos que despuseram seus tempos para me ajudarem, de verdade.

Comment: talvez o teu problema esteja neste `r` antes do `'ju(iz|íza)`, me parece gerar um erro de sintaxe. não tenho certeza, mas é o que parece.

Comment: Já tentei de varios jeitos. Nao é no `r` o problema.

Comment: Já tentou dessa forma? https://regex101.com/r/FGK6r2/2 Tem um exemplo da página para que possamos verificar o regex?

Comment: @André Link quebrado. `Not Found`.

Comment: http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1513873742547.txt

Comment: Tenta dessa forma: https://regex101.com/r/FGK6r2/3

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, respondi aqui embaixo. Esse regex nao rolou.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu criei uma versão abaixo com pequenas mudanças na sua regex:

```
import re

f_regex = re.compile(r'^(\b|.+\s)ju(iz|íza) |^(\b|.+\s)relato(r|a) |^(\b|.+\s)desembargado(r|ra) ', re.IGNORECASE)


success = ["juíza Fulana", "Juiz Fulano", "desembargador Fulano", "Desembargadora Fulana", "Sr. Juiz de Tal"]
fail = ["Fulana de Tal", "Fulano de Tal", "Fulano de Tal", "Juízane Fulana de Tal", "Juizo de Tal", "Dajuiz de Tal"]

print("\nDeve encontrar:")
for string in success:
    result = f_regex.match(string)
    print(string,'- encontrou?',result!=None)

print("\nNao deve encontrar:")
for string in fail:
    result = f_regex.match(string)
    print(string,'- encontrou?',result!=None)
```

Criei algumas strings para testar também. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Também nao rolou Dhiogo

Comment: Você tem como passar algum exemplo dos dados que não estão dando certo?

Comment: Respondi aqui embaixo

Answer (score 0):

Galera, boa parte dos problemas era por causa dos espaços.

Pasta com alguns txts: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aqUjO4x3cvmKFYJJZJKV8dMmDxGGBOqq?usp=sharing

A seguinte funçao pega boa parte(juiz, relator, desembargador), mas nao está pegando juiza relatora. Talvez o problema seja no `masculino|feminino`:

```
def find_juiz(file):
file_lines = list(reversed(line_tokenize(file)))[:10]
file_chunked = str(file_lines)
name_juiz = ''
search = re.search(r'ju(iz|íza)\s*relato(r|ra)|ju(iz|íza)|relato(r|ra)|desembargado(r|ra)',file_chunked)
if search is not None:
    for i,line in enumerate(file_lines):
        if line.strip() in search.group():
            # while file_lines[i+1] is not None:
            #     j=i
            #     name_juiz += file_lines[j+1]
            #     j+=1
            # return name_juiz
            return i,line.strip()
else:
    return
```

ps: esse `line_tokenize` vem do pacote `nltk`(Natural Language Tool Kit), que é um pacote pra trabalhar com NLP (Natural Language Processing) em Python. Ele recebe um texto e o separa em uma lista de linhas, onde cada posiçao é uma linha. Como é um padrao que os nomes dos juízes estão no final eu reverti essa lista com `reversed` e peguei as ultimas(que agora sao as primeiras) 10 linhas (`list(reversed(line_tokenize(file)))[:10]`)

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o texto publicado no comentário da pergunta: http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1513873742547.txt

É possível capturar essas informações com o regex `\b(.+)(?:\n.*)(?:relatora?|desembargadora?|ju[íi]za?)`

Explicação:

> **\b(.+)** => Aqui vamos capturar um padrão no inicio. Como definimos **.+**, ele vai pegar todo o conteúdo até a quebra de linha. (Item abaixo)
>
> **(?:\n.*)** => Aqui informamos para o algoritmo para capturar todo o código da linha seguinte.
>
> **(?:relatora?|desembargadora?|ju[íi]za?)** => Aqui nós filtramos algumas palavras. Adicionamos um **?** para informar que a palavra anterior a ele é opcional.
>
> **?:** => Essa opção utilizamos para evitar que esses dados sejam capturamos, queremos que esse grupo seja apenas validado.

**[Regex em funcionamento](https://regex101.com/r/FGK6r2/3)**

Comment: Nao encontrou nada com esse regex Valdeir.

Answer (score 0):

### Primeiro problema:

o seu regex não vai funcionar com `.match`, ele exige que case **completamente** a string com a sua regex.

### Segundo problema:

Outra coisa, o teu arquivo `.txt` pode estar em **UTF-8** e por isto ele pode não reconhecer os acentos, então se estiver usando `urllib` (acaso leia os arquivos remotamente) no `read()` (do `urllib`) do handler adicione o `.decode('utf-8')`

Se o seu documento for em ASCII ou windows-1252 ou iso-8859-1 no `open()` adicione o parâmetro `encoding`:

Veja os exemplos no final da resposta

### Terceiro problema:

Tua regex esta buscando qualquer coisa que contenha espaços antes e depois, lembre-se frases podem terminar em pontuações como `.`, `!`, `?`, etc e também podem ser separadas por `,`, `;`, `:`, ou até mesmo serem isoladas por aspas `"`

A sua regex deveria ser algo como:

```
r'(\s|^)(ju(iz|íza) relato(r|a)|ju(iz|íza)|relato(r|a)|desembargado(r|ra))[!?",;:.\s]'
```

- O `\s` no começo indica que pode conter espaço, quebra de linha ou tabulação
- O `[!?",;:.\s]` indica que pode haver pontuações no final da palavra e o `\s` indica que pode espaços espaços, quebra de linha ou tabulação no final da palavra.

---

### Exemplo se for baixar de uma URL

Se estiver lendo da URL faça assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re             # importa modulo
import urllib.request # importa modulo

url = "http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1513873742547.txt"
parttern = r'(\s|^)(ju(iz|íza) relato(r|a)|ju(iz|íza)|relato(r|a)|desembargado(r|ra))[!?",;:.\s]'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    data = f.read().decode('utf-8')

    p = re.compile(parttern)
    resultado = p.search(data)

    print(resultado)
```

Se o arquivo **remoto** estiver em windows-1252 ou iso-8859-1 use assim:

```
data = f.read().decode('latin1')
```

### Exemplo se for ler um arquivo na maquina

Se o arquivo `.txt` estiver em `utf-8` use `encoding='utf-8'`, se for windows-1252 ou iso-8859-1 use `encoding='latin1'`

```
import re

arquivo = 'foobar.txt'
parttern = r'(\s|^)(ju(iz|íza) relato(r|a)|ju(iz|íza)|relato(r|a)|desembargado(r|ra))[!?",;:.\s]'

with open(arquivo, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

    p = re.compile(parttern)
    resultado = p.search(data)

    print(resultado)
```

Comment: Entao Guilherme, na verdade o regex que estou usando está funcionando. Ele so nao pega juíza relatora dentre os txts que deixei compartilhado no google drive. de resto está pegando tudo. Esse seu regex nao funcionou, pegou alguns relatores e alguns juizes relatores.

Comment: @André eu fiz o teste exatamente como esta e funcionou bem, você entendeu a parte do `enconding`? Não é o meu regex que não funcionou, é o seu enconding que não deve estar ajustado. Por favor tente novamente.

Comment: Sim, estava usando `encoding` desde o começo. Já descobri qual era o problema. Nao era na regex e sim na linha `if line.strip() in search.group():`. O certo é o contrário: `if search.group() in line.strip():`.
Na verdade, essa simples regex funciona: `r'ju(iz|íza)|relato(r|ra)|desembargado(r|ra)'`

Comment: @André isso de group você não citou na pergunta, não tinha como ninguem imaginar aonde tinha sido o problema né?

Comment: Sim, eu realmente achava que era no regex. Depois respondi aqui mandando o código da funçao, onde estava o erro. Descupem pelo erro.